# Unable to get text from element when calling to it 2nd time in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I am trying to get the value of the element, then click another element and see how that value changes. I have no problem getting the value the first time, but when I try to get it after I've clicked another one, the value returns as "-" or an empty string even though the method is identical to the one that returned the correct value the first time. Here's the code.

```js
it('select/unselect services and verify price change', () => {
                    cy.get('[data-qa="subtotal"]')
                    .invoke('text')
                    .then((originalSubtotal) => {
                        cy.log(originalSubtotal)  //returns "$xxx.xx" string #1 here
                        //get the TPMS price
                        cy.get('.summary-line')
                            .invoke('text')
                            .then((tpmsText) => {
                                cy.log(tpmsText) //returns "$xxx.xx" string #2
                                //click TPMS checkbox
                                cy.get('.icon-checkmark')
                                    .click()
                                    .then(()=> {
                                        cy.get('[data-qa="subtotal"]')
                                        .invoke('text')
                                        .then((newSubtotal) => {
                                        cy.log(newSubtotal) //returns empty string or "-" even though the code is identical to what returned string #1
                                        })
                                    
                                    })
                            })


             })
    
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not comparing values then you write all statements in sequence rather than writing it inside `then`

```js
it('select/unselect services and verify price change', () => {
  cy.get('[data-qa="subtotal"]')
    .invoke('text')
    .then((originalSubtotal) => {
      cy.log(originalSubtotal) //returns "$xxx.xx" string #1 here
    })

  //get the TPMS price
  cy.get('.summary-line')
    .invoke('text')
    .then((tpmsText) => {
      cy.log(tpmsText) //returns "$xxx.xx" string #2
    })

  //click TPMS checkbox
  cy.get('.icon-checkmark').click()

  cy.get('[data-qa="subtotal"]')
    .invoke('text')
    .then((newSubtotal) => {
      cy.log(newSubtotal)
    })
})
```

Comment: I will be comparing values later. Just wanted to resolve this issue before moving on.

Comment: What values would you be comparing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that the 2nd value check happened too quickly after the click. Adding a 2 sec wait between the click and the value check solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're checking for a change, using `should()` will be better than `cy.wait(2000)`.

It's always better to assert with an retry than to `cy.log()`.

```js
cy.get('[data-qa="subtotal"]')
  .invoke('text')
  .then((originalSubtotal) => {

    cy.get('.icon-checkmark').click()  //click TPMS checkbox

    cy.get('[data-qa="subtotal"]')
      .invoke('text')
      .should('not.eq', originalSubtotal)   // up to 4 seconds retry
  })
```